# How can I vertically center text beside images in my profile page?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I have added some information into my SO profile like below image.

[image]

In this image you clearly see that the link is not vertically centered with regards to the image icon, but I'd *like* it to be, like in the image below.

[image]

So can some one please guide me on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can! Images are baseline-aligned with the line of text they're sitting on, meaning their bottom will be in line with the bottom of the text.

You *could* use a HTML image tag with the right vertical alignment, but that would require using the style attribute, which is blocked for good reason.

Have you considered using an icon that's roughly as high as the text instead?

Comment: @JH all right but i have one question _is SO provide kind of Table Structure_ ?

Comment: No, we don't have tables.

Comment: and another question is if i make one HTML page that contains this type of Structure then i load HTML page into my Profile? so is that possible.

Comment: Goodness, no, that'd be terribly insecure. You're limited to little more than what markdown can do, and markdown can't do this.

Comment: so there is no way to achieve this right. this is so BAD.

Comment: @MD There's one way (noted) but generally, SO's formatting _isn't for_ the kind of thing you're trying to do.

Comment: @JH thank u very much for giving me such useful information.